# How to automatically increase/decrease text size in label in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application where I have a textedit and a label. When a user presses the button, the textedit text should be displayed on label. For the label I have set few properties like word wrap is enabled and horizontal and vertically it is aligned center. Below is the screenshot :

[image]

Now I have to automatically adjust the size of the text in label so that if someone enters a large string, then it should fit inside the label, that means size of text should decrease. And if the text string is small, then size should increase automatically to fill up the complete label. Currently if I am typing it the large string, it looks like something:

[image]

As you can see, in the above image, text is moving out of the label. It should remain inside the label.

How to detect in application if the text is moving out of the label height & width. Then how to reduce the text size. I want the size to automatically increase if the string is small and decrease it string is large to fill up the complete label. Is there any class or something provided in QT. Any help or example please. Thanks.

EDIT: With the below code I am able to reduce the size of text to fit inside the label width but not able to make the text multi line.

```
QString string = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();   //Getting data from textEdit

ui->label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);   //Aligning label text to center
QFont f("Arial",50);        //Setting the default font size to 50
QFontMetrics fm(f);
ui->label->setFont(f);      //Setting the font to the label
int width = fm.width(string);   //Getting the width of the string
int size;
while(width >= 870)     //870 is the max width of label
{

    size = ui->label->font().pointSize()-1;     //Reduce font size by 1
    QFont newFont("Arial",size);            
    QFontMetrics nfm(newFont);          
    ui->label->setFont(newFont);        //Set the new font with new size
    width = nfm.width(string);      //Get the new width
}
ui->label->setText(string);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577062/1329652) might be a good starting point, and see also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40874113/1329652) for labels in a layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You (S. Andrew) solved it a little bit different like I proposed (just a statement but not critics). You did the word wrapping by yourself.

I wrote a minimal complete application to check how the Qt internal word wrapping can be used for your problem:

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStyle>

using namespace std;

class Label: public QLabel {

  public:
    void layout();
    QRect documentRect(); // borrowed from QLabelPrivate
  protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent);
};

QRect Label::documentRect()
{
  QRect rect = contentsRect();
  int m = margin(); rect.adjust(m, m, -m, -m);
  layoutDirection();
  const int align
    = QStyle::visualAlignment(layoutDirection(), QLabel::alignment());
  int i = indent();
  if (i < 0 && frameWidth()) { // no indent, but we do have a frame
    m = fontMetrics().width(QLatin1Char('x')) / 2 - m;
  }
  if (m > 0) {
    if (align & Qt::AlignLeft) rect.setLeft(rect.left() + m);
    if (align & Qt::AlignRight) rect.setRight(rect.right() - m);
    if (align & Qt::AlignTop) rect.setTop(rect.top() + m);
    if (align & Qt::AlignBottom) rect.setBottom(rect.bottom() - m);
  }
  return rect;
}

void Label::layout()
{
  // get initial settings
  QString text = this->text();
  QRect rectLbl = documentRect(); // wrong: contentsRect();
  QFont font = this->font();
  int size = font.pointSize();
  QFontMetrics fontMetrics(font);
  QRect rect = fontMetrics.boundingRect(rectLbl,
    Qt::TextWordWrap, text);
  // decide whether to increase or decrease
  int step = rect.height() > rectLbl.height() ? -1 : 1;
  // iterate until text fits best into rectangle of label
  for (;;) {
    font.setPointSize(size + step);
    QFontMetrics fontMetrics(font);
    rect = fontMetrics.boundingRect(rectLbl,
      Qt::TextWordWrap, text);
    if (size <= 1) {
      cout << "Font cannot be made smaller!" << endl;
      break;
    }
    if (step < 0) {
      size += step;
      if (rect.height() < rectLbl.height()) break;
    } else {
      if (rect.height() > rectLbl.height()) break;
      size += step;
    }
  }
  // apply result of iteration
  font.setPointSize(size);
  setFont(font);
}

void Label::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QLabel::resizeEvent(pQEvent);
  layout();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cout << QT_VERSION_STR << endl;
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QGroupBox qGBox;
  QVBoxLayout qBox;
  Label qLbl;
  qLbl.setFrameStyle(Label::Box);
  qLbl.setFrameShadow(Label::Sunken);
  qLbl.setWordWrap(true);
  qBox.addWidget(&qLbl, 1);
  QLineEdit qTxt;
  qBox.addWidget(&qTxt, 0);
  qGBox.setLayout(&qBox);
  qWin.setCentralWidget(&qGBox);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTxt, &QLineEdit::editingFinished,
    [&qTxt, &qLbl]() {
      QString text = qTxt.text();
      qLbl.setText(text);
      qLbl.layout();
    });
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

Compiled and tested with VS2013 / Qt 5.6 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: Snapshot of testQFontMetric.exe]

When playing around with this test application, I recognized that the text fits not everytimes perfectly into the `QLabel`. I tried to improve the code exchanging `QRect rectLbl = rect();` with `QRect rectLbl = contentsRect();`. This made it better but still not perfect. It seems there is some finetuning necessary (where the development starts to become effort). (*See update at end of text.*)

Actually, it would not be necessary to derive `QLabel`. In my first implementation, `layout()` was a function with `QLabel&` and `const QString&` as parameters.

After I got the font size management working, I intended to consider resize events also. Googling a little bit, I found the solution to apply event filters. However, event filters are called *before* the event is processed but I need *after*. Finally, I decided to inherit `QLabel` and to overload `QLabel::resizeEvent()` to keep things simple.

Btw. I noticed it is even not necessary to set

> height eventually to a very large value

as I suggested in a comment earlier. It seems that [`QFontMetrics::boundingRect(const QRect &rect, int flags, ...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2) increases the height automa[gt]ically to keep required width when `Qt::TextWordWrap` is enabled.

Update:

@annacarolina encouraged me to investigate a little bit deeper into this issue that font size is sometimes choosen to large. Some debugging in `Label::layout()` uncovered that sometimes computed `rect` looked like unwrapped text where visual output was wrapped. This made me suspiciuous about correctness of the `rectLbl`. Thus, I started in [qlabel.cpp on woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html) but actually the Qt forum [QLabel: Resize font to contentsRect](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/66425-QLabel-Resize-font-to-contentsRect) provided the final hint which leaded me to [`QLabelPrivate::documentRect()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html#_ZNK13QLabelPrivate12documentRectEv) (actually again on woboq.org where I already had looked for enlightment). Thus, I added a method `Label::documentRect()` to my class. This makes results much better (although I'm not fully convinced about "perfect").

Comment: Thanks for this good example. I am also facing simillar issue. Can you explain your code a little bit. I think the main logic is inside this `void Label::layout()`. Can you explain it. Thanks :)

Comment: `QRect rectLbl = contentsRect();` in this I am getting `400x300` but actually my window is full screen so label is also full screen. It should return `1366x768`. How to do it

Comment: @annacarolina I just tested my app again (on Windows 10) and made it full-screen. The text was re-layouted and increased, appropriately. In your case, I suspect there could be trouble concerning `resizeEvent()`. In [another sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833511/qt-how-to-create-image-that-scale-with-window-and-keeps-aspect-ratio/42852010#42852010), I observed similar issues which I could fix by a work-around - applying a frame to the label. (The frame may force a sufficient re-layout on every size change what's needed there and here.)

Comment: I somehow managed to do it but it increases more than its resolution. My current height and width is 1366x768. So the width remains less than 1366 but the height goes more than 768. Is there any way to reduce the height too

Comment: @annacarolina I believe I fixed it. Source code is updated and there is a note about this at end of my answer.

Comment: Yes. I set the height value manually. So now it seems to work. I will test it with more test cases later. Thanks.!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @Scheff. I just had to add a check for `rect.width()` in `Label::layout()`, to correct the situations when height already fits, but width doesn't. Also, I was surprised, that `QLabel::setFont()` doesn't work when the label's font is set in Qt stylesheet, even for parent widgets, when the label just inherits the font size from its parent hierarchy. So one has to make sure that there is no `font-size` rule in the stylesheet which would be inherited by the target `Label`.

Comment: @MichalFapso I must admit that I've no experience with styles in Qt. For what I'm doing usually, the default look&feel is mostly sufficient.

Comment: @MichalFapso Your note about `rect.width()`, I didn't understand. The algorithm is based on text floating. If the width isn't matching then the floating doesn't work correctly. That may happen in extreme cases (no wrapping can be applied for a line). OK, something I didn't consider... (Using another wrap mode would fix this but I assume that was not intended in your case.)

Comment: You're right, @Scheff. Your code behaves correctly. Just in my case, my QLabel had a fixed size (minSize == maxSize) and for that reason I needed to add the check for width. Here is the code with screenshots: https://gist.github.com/michalfapso/f1ecac7e81dc986cb3bc941abe85d5e4

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, I am making a logic where I am first getting all the words in the string. Then I am appending the words in `QList<QString> data` and checking if the width of the appended words is smaller than then width of the label. If the width goes above the width of label then I break it using `\n`. So in this way I made a list of the sub strings whose total width is around the width of the label and saved it in the List. Then I am calculating the width of sub strings  stored in the list and then decreasing its font size till its total width is less than width of the label. After this I am displaying it on the label.

```
QList<QString> data;
CountWords Word;
ui->label->clear();
QString string = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();   //Getting data from textEdit
QStringList count = Word.GetWords(string);   //Here I get the list of words in string
ui->label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);   //Aligning label text to center
QFont f("Arial",50);        //Setting the default font size to 50
QFontMetrics fm(f);
ui->label->setFont(f);      //Setting the font to the label
int size,fontSize;
QString temp = ui->label->text();
int last = count.size();
//Saving the words in QList
for(int i=0;i<count.size();i++)
{
    temp.append(count[i]+" ");
    size = fm.width(temp);
    if(size > 870)
    {
        temp.append("\n");
        data << temp;
        //data.append(temp);
        temp.clear();
    }
    if((last-1)==i)
    {
         subString.append("\n");
         data << subString;
         subString.clear();
    }
}

 //decreasing the font size
QList<int> wide;
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
    wide << fm.width(data[i]);
    while(wide[i] >= 870)
    {
        fontSize = ui->label->font().pointSize() - 1;
        QFont newFont("Arial",fontSize);
        QFontMetrics nfm(newFont);
        ui->label->setFont(newFont);
        wide[i] = 0;
        wide[i] = nfm.width(data[i]);
    }

}

//Finally displaying it on label
QString labelData;
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
    labelData = ui->label->text();
    labelData.append(data[i]);
    ui->label->setText(labelData);

}
```